# Does the Prospero X-1 have an USB port?

Tags: mining-hardware, asic

I have looked everywhere but cannot find out whether the Black Arrow Prospero X-1 has a USB port for connecting to a computer (and interfacing with miner to start mining). Does it have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the explorer and typing the ip adresse for the prospero, and then you get a web interface for setup.